# Detect when player is colliding with a particle - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just made a **Particle System** that spawns a ***"lava"*** particle every **1** second (with **various sizes**, **colors** etc.). I need the player to **respawn when colliding with one of these lava particles** (The *respawn()* function already exists and works, now it just needs to be called at the right time). I did quite a lot of research on *Unity answers* and other sites, as well as *StackOverflow*, but didn't understand how to do this.

Here's a screenshot of **how the particle system is now**. I enabled the ***trigger*** checkbox and tried changing a few things but with no success:

[image]

And this code should be **called when the player has touched a lava particle**:

```cs
private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Lava"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(TouchedLava());
    }
}
```

**I'm not getting any errors** (even at runtime) in the console.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to check the Collision part of the particle system, just above Triggers, and then set the Collision type to World.

I think this tutorial might help you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRa2g3vgzBo&list=PLX2vGYjWbI0QJJfR-jSqxonYuCHrUhAvN

[image]

Edit:

Here is my working Script:

```
public class ParticleTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem part;

    void Start()
    {
        part = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
           Debug.Log(other.tag);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what you suggested to do did not work.

Comment: Ok, here is my working scrit, just in case:                                                               
public class particleTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem part;

    void Start()
    {
        part = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player")
        Debug.Log(other.tag);
    }
}

Comment: Thank you really much. I was not sure where to put the script with the ```onParticleCollisionEvent();```, and had in the _colliders_ section 3d mode instead of 2d (when my game is 2d!). So, thanks for the answer and edit! :)